# Opening new shell makes browser open Apple "man" page

Tags: macos, iterm2

Every time I start, or open a new shell within iTerm/Terminal, the default browser loads [a (broken) Apple man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/11.html).

The preference file gives no clue as far as I can see as to why this occurs. 
Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That Google URL is just 2 hours old, and has not been used a lot: http://goo.gl/#analytics/goo.gl/RjyhlP/all_time -- did you create it? Quite confusing!

Comment: Since you've been back here, but didn't respond, I've removed the Google link. You can [use "rollback" on the 2nd revision](http://superuser.com/posts/695678/revisions) if that link is really used.

Comment: @Arjan I used the url shortner on a rather long address thinking it would become a
live link with the angle brackets. I'm afraid I don't understand much of what you are explaining in your two comments.

Comment: Your question stated *"the default browser loads above URL"*, which referred to the Google URL. That simply made me think that the browser was opening that Google URL, while in fact it was opening the Apple URL directly. I don't think there was any need for the URL shortener, and I also feel that people want to know what they click on, so I dislike using URL shorteners when not needed. And in this very case it also added unneeded confusion... For example: *maybe* Apple uses their own URL somewhere in their OS, but they surely wouldn't use the Google URL. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that one of the `$SHELL` startup files initiates or opens something?  Do `$ echo $SHELL` in that terminal to see which command interpreter you are using.  I'm not sure what `iTerm/Terminal` is, but if it starts any one of the usual command interpreters (`bash`, `csh`, `sh`, `ksh`, etc.), then a startup file will be sourced.  Each interpreter uses its own set.  Check the `man` page for your particular one to find out which files to check.  For instance, `bash` sources some or all of these files, depending on file permissions and existence - taken straight from the `bash` `man` page:

```
   /etc/profile
          The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
   ~/.bash_logout
          The  individual  login shell cleanup file, executed when a login
          shell exits
   ~/.inputrc
          Individual readline initialization file
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm on bash so have scowered the above files but have found no indication of why the browser activates as yet.

Comment: I assume you are referring to [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net) and not [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home). I'm using `FinkCommander` to install `gnome-terminal` to get a replacement to Mavericks `Terminal` as I type - that huge compile has my MBP Retina's fans spinning.  Will give `iTerm` a try.  Can you give pointers as to how to replicate this specific problem?

Comment: Got, installed, and am using `iTerm2` - the note at `iTerm` said that project was dead, and to get `iTerm2` - so I did.  It works fine at present.  Would you please describe what steps you performed to get the problem, and which specific version you are using?  If you were to create a new user account just to try `iTerm2`, do you have the same or similar problem?

Comment: Got `gnome-terminal` running in Mavericks `XQuartz`. Because of very long scroll buffers, the granularity of using the scrollbar for the std `Terminal` app didn't allow for minor adjustments in the `Terminal`'s view when 100's of lines had already scrolled by, so I either had to use a VM for `Ubuntu`'s Terminal, use a terminal in `XEmacs`'s `shell` `minor-mode`, or find a way to get `X` to load a window manager that provides that widget.  Fortunately, `Fink` already had the `gnome-terminal` distribution bundled and ready to compile on `Mavericks`.  Had to move `brew`, though...  A new topic.